# Select a symbol at the beginning of provided regular expression

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I would like to use regular expression `r"'\w+\.\w{4}[^']*"` to select the single quote `'` like so:

```
teststring = "Lorem 'happy_little.pony?eatingGreenb4nana' ipsum 'dontSelectMeOrMy.Quotes' ameno."
# select me         ^
```

Right now the reg.expression that I provided above selects `'happy_little.pony?eatingGreenb4nana` so I tried to use parenthesis to target like this `r"(')\w+\.\w{4}[^']*"` with no luck.

---

**Explanation of regular expression i provided:**

Select; starting with (`'`) one or more (`+`) word characters (`\w`) before a dot (`\.`) and 4 more word characters (`\w{4}`) with 0 or more symbols not including  (`[^']`) after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do want to achieve with the selected quote? What you can use is a [lookahead regex](http://regular-expressions.mobi/lookaround.html?wlr=1), but I can imagine that you're asking about your solution instead of about your problem (XY problem).

Try this:

```
r"'(?=\w+\.\w{4}[^']*')"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Congrats on 10k reputation :D